# Canon G12 has no display but takes pictures

Tags: canon

My G12 will take pictures on auto setting using the viewfinder, but the display is dark. Not totally dark; there is a faint glow which goes when I switch off the display. I've opened the back and cleaned the ribbon connector. The flexible wire connection looks ok. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Unless you've changed some setting somewhere, it sounds like it needs looking at by Canon.

Comment: Using the viewfinder? Maybe you meant preview screen?

Comment: I believe he means the LCD screen on the back of the camera.

Comment: No, the screen (display) is dark. The camera has an optical viewfinder.

Comment: Some might say anything that stops one from "chimping" is a good thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may be easily fixed. My guess is you did what I did, and inadvertently pushed the DISP. (display) button next to the MENU button on the lower righthand corner on the back of the camera. The DISP. button toggles between 3 views: black/blank screen (to save charge/battery life), regular view, and a display with a handy level and rule of thirds guidelines. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to turn the display off when taking pictures.  It conserves the battery.  I cannot remember if the setting is in the menu or it can be changed by pushing one of the other buttons on the camera.  If the display works properly when you are reviewing the pictures that you have already taken then the above is the problem.   If the display is also dark when you are reviewing pictures then you have a camera problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The display does not turn on at all apart from the faint glow I mentioned. It turns that faint glow off if I press the display off button.I can only review pictures by loading them onto a computer. I was hoping someone might know what the problem is. I have a good display from a G11 which I could try if nobody has experience of this.Cheers.